# recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I want to retreive at the finaly of call recursive method, a set of integer with result :
{10,20,30} but in this program i have porblem ,

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap();
     myMap.put(1, new HashSet(){{add(10);}});
     myMap.put(2, new HashSet(){{add(20);}});myMap.get(2).add(30);
     myMap.put(3, new HashSet());

     HashSet<Integer> setInteg = new HashSet();
     recursivFonc(setInteg, myMap, 1);
     System.out.println(setInteg);
}

static HashSet recursivFonc(HashSet<Integer> setInteg, HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> map, int cont)
{
    System.out.println(cont);
    if(map.get(cont) != null)
    {
        Set<Integer> set = map.get(cont);
        for(Integer intg : set)
        {

            setInteg.add(intg);
            return recursivFonc(setInteg, map, cont);
        }
    }
    return setInteg;
}
```

how did I do to get to the end a set with {10,20,30} ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `return` statement inside the for loop. Because of this, the for loop iterates only once. Instead, move the return statement outside of the for-loop. Therefore; the loop will iterate over all elements of the set.

You might also want to increment `cont` at each recursive call. Because the exit point for the recursive calls depends on whether `map.get(cont)` is null or not. If you never change the value of `cont`, it is `1` initially. Each call to the method will be passed `1` and it will go on for a long time (until you are out of memory, I guess).

```
static HashSet recursivFonc(HashSet<Integer> setInteg, HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> map, int cont)
    {
        System.out.println(cont);
        if(map.get(cont) != null)
        {
            Set<Integer> set = map.get(cont);
            for(Integer intg : set)
            {

                setInteg.add(intg);
            }
            return recursivFonc(setInteg, map, cont + 1);
        }
        return setInteg;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, it's going to crash very fast due to a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Oups yes of corse !  but why result is [10, 20] and not [10, 20, 30] ?
`return recursivFonc(setInteg, map, cont+1);`

Comment: @user1149157 - The result should be `[20, 10, 30]` as expected? Have you tried incrementing `cont` **and** moving the return statement outside the loop.

Comment: when i execute this programe, set result is [10, 20] and normally it is [10, 20, 30]